# AsyncPipe in *ngIf

Tags: angular5, rxjs5

I am trying to show one of the headers according to the value of `isComplex$` observable in *ngIf:

```
<complex-header *ngIf="isComplex$ | async; else ordinaryHeader"></complexheader>
<ng-template #ordinaryHeader>
  <ordinary-header></ordinary-header>
</ng-template>
```

The problem is `*ngIf` goes with else case without waiting for observable to emit value. How can I accomplish both of headers wait for observable to emit its first value.

Comment: so you want it to display `complex-header` when `isComplex$` is resolved to true, and display `ordinary-header` when `isComplex$` is resolved to false. What do you want to display then, when `isComplex$` is **NOT** resolved yet?

Comment: For now it doesn't matter, is it important? I mean I know it's stupid UX, but for now I am just interested if there is a way to do this using asyncpipe?

Comment: no, it does matter. Cos your case now, it is exactly showing `ordiary-header` when it is **unresolved**.  That is because when unresolved, your `ngIf` is treating it as falsy, hence it will be showing `ordinary-header`. So technically it is behaving correctly, unless you specifically said `unresolved` has another specific header.

Comment: So I can't use ngIf else here, but two seperate ngIf s and two asyncpipes? Can I do it with only one asyncpipe?

Comment: You are right. That is because `ngIf` is never meant for `async` purposes. There is lots of workaround though. If you insist to use a single async pipe, there is always a lag time before async is resolved and the template rendered. If you do not want to provide another specific header for `unresolved` scenario then its moot.

Comment: Of course, that's right, I will put some loading there. Can you give any recommended workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to not use async pipe multiple times is to wrap everything in a ng-container with the async pipe and use `*ngFor`. But to use `*ngFor` isComplex$ must always emit an itterable. So we need a new observable to use in the template:

```
isComplexIterable$ = isComplex$.pipe(map(isComplex => [isComplex]))

<ng-container *ngFor="let isComplex of isComplexIterable$ | async">
   <complex-header *ngIf="isComplex"></complexheader>
   <ordinary-header *ngIf="!isComplex"></ordinary-header>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I've already tried this. It doesn't work if isComplex$ emits `false` which removes entire ng-container from DOM and therefore ordinary-header too. Just emit `false` in your demo, see what happens.

Comment: Now it shows ordinary-header in the beginning without waiting for observable to resolve

Answer (score 3):

Use angular5 *ngIf else directive.

```
<div class="course-detail" *ngIf="isComplex$ | async as isComplex else ordinary">
   <complex-header *ngIf="isComplex"></complex-header>
   <ordinary-header *ngIf="!isComplex"></ordinary-header>
</div>
<!-- Showing ordinary header for cases when observable is not returned this can be replaced wuth loader as well-->
<ng-template #ordinary>
    <ordinary-header></ordinary-header>
</ng-template>
```

Also see https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-reactive-templates/

Comment: How is this different from my code? It will still render `ordinary-header` without waiting for observable.

Comment: @Hikmat seems like I misunderstood your scenario. I thought you need to show ordinary while loading .